# pyephem "DeprecationWarning" while setting latitude from string

Tags: python-2.7, pyephem

I am trying to run the following (creating an observer and setting its position):

```
import ephem
vlt = ephem.Observer()
vlt.lat = '-24:37:38'
```

I get:

```
DeprecationWarning: PyOS_ascii_strtod and PyOS_ascii_atof are deprecated.  Use PyOS_string_to_double instead.
```

this is not so dramatic, because the code still works, but it pollutes my iPython outpout because I call hundreds of times:

```
vlt.date = date
```

which also gives the deprecation warning.

I would be happy simply by getting rid of the hundreds of deprecation warnings. Note that I am calling the script from iPython, so I cannot use "-W ignore::DeprecationWarning" as far as I know...

thanks in advance!

My configuration (if relevant): Mac OS 10.8.5, Python 2.7.5

Comment: So then edit the source code of the module.